# IndexOutOfRange Exception When Click On DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, indexoutofrangeexception

Last Week I'm Working On A WinFroms Project And I Created A **Cart** Form.
In Cart, There Is A **DataGridView** Control & It Contains A Column Named **purchasedQuantity**.
**purchasedQuantity** Is Editable & User Can Enter Value Only In This Column. Here Is The EvenHandler For **CellEndEdit**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.RowIndex <= 0 || e.ColumnIndex != 4)
        return;

    int row = e.RowIndex;
    int demandedQuantity = int.Parse(this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["purchasedQuantity"].Value.ToString());
    int inStockQunatity = int.Parse(this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["unitsInStock"].Value.ToString());
    double price = double.Parse(this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["unitPrice"].Value.ToString());

    if (demandedQuantity <= inStockQunatity)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["subTotal"].Value = (demandedQuantity * price).ToString();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["unitsInStock"].Value = (inStockQunatity - demandedQuantity).ToString();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["purchasedQuantity"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("We Have Only {0} Left In The Stock..!!", inStockQunatity.ToString()), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["purchasedQuantity"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

The Problem Is That Whenever I Click On Any Cell Of The DataGridView, I Get The Following Error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Index -1 does not have a value.
Make sure that the maximum index on a list is less than the list size
Make sure the index is not a negative number.
Make sure data column names are correct.

I Have A **Home** Form That Create **ViewProduct** Form Instance And That **ViewProduct** Form Creates **Cart** Form Instance & I Get Error In The **Home** Form In The Following Function:
Home => ViewProdcuts => Cart

```
 private void ShowForm(Form form) 
 {
      this.Hide();
      form.ShowDialog();

      form.Close();
      this.Show();
 }
```

On The Following Line:

```
form.ShowDialog();
```

As I Mentioned First, I Start Working On It Last Week. At That Time It Works Fine, No Exceptions Are Thrown On Clicking On Any Row & I Was Able To Enter Value In The **purchasedQuanttiy** Cell.
After One Week It Get Angry, Don't Know Why (Just Kidding)
I Googled That Problem But Found No Answer. Can Anybody Please Tell Me What Is Wrong With This Code.
Thanks In Advance For Reply

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: @Steve Please Read Question Again, I Edited It & Put Answer Of Your Question There As This Should Be In The Question To Find The Error! 
Thanks

Comment: You should use a debugger. Put a breakpoint on the form.Show method and then follow the code step by step pressing the F11 key until you reach the point of the exception. Now you should have a clearer view of the situation and let us know.

Comment: I Do That But In The Debugger Mode, It Also Point To The Same Line **Home Form** When I Click On Any Row In Debugging Mode, It Immediately Show Exception On ShowDailog() Line!

Comment: If you get an exception on show, probably you have a problem in one of the form subroutines that are called when the form is shown or construct. Sometimes you are trying to acceas a control before it is properly constructed

Comment: But I Didn't Change The Code. It Were As It Is As One Week Ago Which Works Fine!

Comment: do you have any other Events on that particular Datagridview?

Comment: No. Only One Event i.e., CellEditEnd Event Is Registered On That DataGridView

Comment: Interesting, Even When I Remove **CellEndEdit Event Handler** I Get The Same Exception! Mean, Exception Is Not Thrown Due To The **CellEndEdit Event**